# send message to gen_server before init

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I am new to erlang, I having following code:

```
-module (test_srv).
-behaviour (gen_server).
-export ([start_link/0, init/1, handle_info/2]).

start_link() ->
  gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [], []).

init([]) ->
  self() ! asdasd,
  {ok, new_state}.

handle_info(Msg, State) ->
  io:format("server got ~p , now state is ~p~n", [Msg, State]),
  {noreply, State}.
```

I test in erl shell:

```
1> {_, P} = test_srv:start_link().
server got asdasd , now state is new_state
```

The problem is, When send a message to server when the server is not initialised and not readly, how dose gen_server handle the message? I have following guesses:

1. gen_server handle the message immediately, and send the message to `handle_info` callback, but will lose initialised state in `init` callback
2. gen_server store the message if not server initialised, and send message after server initialised.

I wanna to know how erlang or gen_server handle this problem? what is the principle of handle message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing by `server is not initialised` you mean the rest of the `init` function being executed. In that case your second guess is correct. It's guaranteed that the `handle_info` will be executed *after* `init` has returned. Since the `gen_server` is a single process, and you're already executing `init`, the messages sent to itself from `init` will only be processed by `gen_server` after `init` has finished executing.